# kotlin - calculate Compound Interest in years

Tags: kotlin

I am using Kotlin and running into a problem while calculating Compound Interest after three years.

I've tried:

```
fun accountInThreeYears(initial: Int, percent: Int): Double = initial + (initial * percent / 100.toDouble()) * 3
```

However, using an online calculator i get a different answer, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the right formula:

```
value after n years = (initial value) x (1 + interest)^n
```

so your function should look like this:

```
fun accountInThreeYears(initial: Int, percent: Int): Double = initial * (1 + percent / 100.toDouble()).pow(3)
```

use this import for the `pow()` method:

```
import kotlin.math.pow
```

Comment: This is a correct answer to your question, @Haithem, could you please accept it if it worked for you?